# mostrar un Object[] en un JList

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un JFrame en el cual coloqué un JList para visualizar un arreglo, pero el arreglo que obtengo es un Object[] ya que compilo el código en matlab, pero el resultado lo proceso en java, este es mi código:

```
private void jButtonOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // Obtiene el path del Folder con el volumen adquirido
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\...\\ProjectColorCT"));

    int show_fileC = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    String pathFolder = null;
    if (show_fileC != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION ){
        File folderName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        pathFolder = folderName.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextPathFolder.setText(pathFolder);
    }
    // ---    
    System.out.println(pathFolder);
    Object[] arrList = null;
    getNameClass nameObj = null;
    try {
        nameObj = new getNameClass();
        arrList = nameObj.getNameSlices(1, pathFolder);
        System.out.println(arrList[0]);

    } catch (MWException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TACframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }         
}
```

En el objeto llamado "arrList" obtengo toda la lista de nombres que quiero mostrar, pero no sé como mostrarla en un JList, he intentado pasar el objeto a un String[] pero no funciona.

Comment: Cual es la estructura de los Objetos en el Array?

Comment: @alanfcm el objeto es el resultado de una función que creo en Matlab:

`function [archivosNombre] = getNameSlices(rutaFolder)
    archivos = dir(fullfile(rutaFolder,'*'));
    %elimina los primeros dos archivos dentro del folder
    archivos(1)= [];
    archivos(1)= [];
    %Obtiene un cell array con todos los nombres de los
    %archivos dentro de la carpeta seleccionada
    archivosNombre = {archivos.name};
end`

Esa función me devuelve un arreglo con los nombres de mis archivos del folder, pero en java yo obtengo ese arreglo como un objeto, que es el que declaro como un Object[]

Comment: @Aridai Solis Puedes crear una lista de es objeto y darle un add por ejemplo: `List<tuObjeto> lista = new arrayList(); lista.add(tuObjeto);`

Comment: Como dice Raul, puedes intentar con `lista.add(arrList[0].toString());`

Comment: He intentado añadir : `ArrayList<arrList> lista = new ArrayList<arrList>();` pero no me deja ya que no lo reconoce como un Objeto, me manda el error de **cannot find symbol** por consiguiente no puedo realizar un .add

Comment: @Aridai Solis que tipo de objeto te devuelve el archivo